# Angular2 get Url parameter and display it on template

Tags: angular

I have an item listing app and with various stores, I managed to set a default store and fetch the items based on `storeId` and build a url param `/store/3`.

What I'm planning to do is to show the `locationName` of this `storeId` in my template say `store 3` is London, so I want to show something like `Collection Store - London` I managed to do it with its `Id` but showing `Collection Store - 3` doesn't really make sense.

This is my stores which is in my `nav.component`

```ts
this.sourceSites = [
  {
    'Id': 1,
    'StoreLocation': 'Eastleigh'
  },
  {
    'Id': 2,
    'StoreLocation': 'Portchester'
  },
  {
    'Id': 3,
    'StoreLocation': 'London'
  },
  {
    'Id': 4,
    'StoreLocation': 'Basingstoke'
  }
]
```

Nav template

```ts
<li *ngFor="let store of sourceSites" 
    [class.active-location]="storeId === store.Id  || (storeName === store.StoreLocation)">
  <a [routerLink]="['/order-screen/store/' + store.Id + '/' +store.StoreLocation]">
      {{ store.StoreLocation}}
  </a>
</li>
```

To show the `storeId`,I have this in my order-component

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     this.storeId = +params['storeId'];
     if (!this.storeId) { 
        this.storeId = DEFAULT_ORIGIN_ID; 
     } 
  })
}
```

To use default `Id 3` I put `export const DEFAULT_ORIGIN_ID = 3`. Though doing this is fine, but this only shows the `StoreId` instead I want to show `StoreLocation`

My attempt is to add another URL parameter `/store/3/Location` and create another `export const DEFAULT_ORIGIN_LOCATION = 'London'` in my sharedService. and put `else if()` condition in the `ngOnInit`

```ts
ngOnInit() {
   this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.storeId = +params['storeId'];
      this.storeName = +params['storeName'];
      if (!this.storeId) { 
         this.storeId = DEFAULT_ORIGIN_ID; 
      } else if (!this.storeName) {
         this.storeName = DEFAULT_ORIGIN_LOCATION;
      }  
    this.getOrdersFromOrigin(this.storeId);
 })
}
```

But when I do this, it shows me  `Collection Store - London` however when I change my location to something else the location `London` persist.

How can I make the `DEFAULT_ORIGIN_NAME` to change when I change my location?

*Edit*
With child route, its not changing the url path now.

```ts
{ path: 'order-screen/store/:storeId', component: OrderComponent, 
   children: [
      {
         path: ':storeName',
         component: OrderComponent,  
      }
   ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have routes like

```
routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/order-screen/store/3/London'}, 
  { path: 'order-screen/store/:storeId', component: SomeComponent, 
       children: [...] }
];
```

then your code should work.

Comment: so it would look like this? `{ path: 'order-screen/store/:storeId', component: OrderComponent, 
       children: '/:storeName' }`

Comment: `children: '/:storeName` is invalid. `children` needs to be a list of routes like `children: [ { path: 'somepath', component: ChildComponent}, ...]`

Comment: yeah got that right, however it's not changing the url to `www.my.com/order-screen/store/:storeId/:storeName` I've edited my post with routes.

Comment: Is the `<li></li>` code still gonna be the same with child route?

Comment: Adding `storeName` seems weird when you already have the `storeId` you can look up the `StoreLocation` from `sourceSites` if you have the id. Or is `StoreLocation` and `StoreName` something different?

Comment: You can use https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html to set a class for the active link.

Comment: Oh its the same just my naming is a bit weird. StoreName and StoreLocation is the same, I'll rename it

Comment: Not sure what the remaining prolem(s) is or are.

Comment: how can I change this `export const DEFAULT_ORIGIN_LOCATION = 'Soho'` to other location when I change location. So as default its selected Soho if I want to change to Portchester then the default should set to Portchester

Comment: I guess I don't understand yet what you try to accomplish. What do you need `DEFAULT_ORIGIN_LOCATION` for? Perhaps a default route with a redirect to some specific route (see my updated answer.

Comment: Maybe this is the simplest one reword it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249956/angular2-url-params-returning-nan