# Angular2 url params returning NaN

Tags: angular

Rewording my previous question, I have this route which gives me something like this `/order-screen/store/1/London`

```
 {
    path: 'order-screen/store/:storeId/:storeLocation',
    component: OrderComponent
  }
```

When I try to get the `storeLocation` using `this.route.params` it returns an error of `NaN`. I want to get the location `London`, not sure if `.params` is the right one to use.

```
this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.storeLocation = +params['storeLocation'];
  console.log('Location >> ', this.storeLocation);
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the `+` from before your params. So..

```
this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
this.storeLocation = params['storeLocation'];
  console.log('Location >> ', this.storeLocation);
})
```

The `+` will convert a string to a number and since "London" is not a number you got the NaN error

Comment: Yeah figured that earlier, somehow my comment to my own question didn't post. But I will give your answer a check :)

Comment: Glad you didn't get stuck there for too long and figured it out on your own :)